How can I root Sharp Rouvo V?
I'm not sure how to root my SHARP ROUVO V (STTM21VAPP_0530). I think it has already been rooted by someone because I have permissions that have been turned off. I'm trying to figure out how to turn them back on because I tried everything but getting in the use the rooted version of my phone.

There's a ranty thread on XDA Forums asking about the same issue, not sure if this device can be rooted in the first place. A bit curious about "permissions that have been turned off". It could be the manufacturer's/cell provider's customization instead of rooted though.
